# Правопис «рука пустелі»

Tags: власні-назви, правопис, велика-мала-літера

Згідно з правилами вживання великої літери в українській мові:

> [Український правопис 2015, § 38.21](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par38p21): Назви пам'яток архітектури, замків, храмів тощо пишуться з великої літери: Андріївська церква, Золоті ворота, Колізей, Почаївська лавра, Хотинський замок, Софійський собор.

Яким має бути написання чилійської пам'ятки архітектури «рука пустелі»? Рука Пустелі, Рука пустелі чи ще інший варіант? У російській Вікіпедії слово «пустелі» пишуть з маленької, [так](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B8), але її не можна назвати достовірним джерелом, тим паче для українського правопису.

Comment: Ви чомусь не додали примітку: «Родові найменування в подібних назвах пишемо з малої букви: _собо́р Свято́го Петра́, собо́р Сан-Ма́рко, храм Васи́лія Блаже́нного, палац Пото́цьких, за́мок Іф, па́м’ятник Володи́миру Вели́кому, портре́т Му́соргського робо́ти Рє́піна, ре́квієм Мо́царта_».

Comment: @stegetsj, а оце я все заплутав — я помилково вставив посилання на [«Правопис» 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=62), але цитата, яку навів Михайло, насправді з [«Правопису» 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par38p21) — і там немає такої примітки про родові найменування (принаймні в тому ж пункті); уже виправив посилання.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мені написання, аналогічне до вжитого з російської Вікіпедії, — **Рука пустелі** — видається цілком правильним. Зазвичай (за відсутності особливих обставин) з великої літери пишуть лише перше слово; і в наведенних Вами ж прикладах саме так: Почаївська лавра, Хотинський замок і т.ін.

Звісно, написання Рука Пустелі теоретично теж можливе, якщо ми маємо на увазі Пустелю, а не пустелю: тобто з особливою повагою або якусь живу істоту (наприклад, богиню, дух абощо, що уособлює пустелю), а не просто пустелю. Але навіть в іспанському оригіналі Mano del desierto слово desierto «пустеля» пишеться за малої літери, тож не бачу сенсу писати пустелю з великої.

(P.S.: Іноді з великої літери пишуть не перше слово, як-от вулиця Будівельників, але це у випадку, коли перше слово просто показує тип об'єкта/явища, а тут воно є частиною назви скульптури.)